# How to keep entered data in fragments when navigation forward and backward through fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have three fragments: `FragmentA`, `FragmentB`, `FragmentC`. All fragments have one `TextInputLayout` with `editText` inside and `button` to go to next fragment. When `FragmentA` gets called I enter text in `editText` and go to next fragment (`FragmentB`) and do the same thing and do the same thing for last fragment (`FragmentC`). If I go back to `FragmentB` and type something different in `editText` and go to `FragmentC` text that was three is gone. I know that I have to pass bundle to fragment that will be displayed when swipe back on phone using`onDetach()` method. I know if I want to pass bundle to fragment that I will call with pressing next button I have to `setArguments(bundle)`.

```
public void switchFragments(Fragment fragment, Fragment currentFragment, boolean addToBackStack, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = currentFragment.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_sign_up, fragment, tag);
    transaction.hide(currentFragment);
    if(addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I am using `transaction.add()` and `transaction.hide()` because I am losing text entered in `editTexts` when I am coming back from previous fragment if I use transaction.replace()

Answer (score 0):

To store and keep values between Fragments, look at `SharedPreferences`. Use this to pass value between fragments.

```
holder.YOURBUTTONCLICKID.setOnClickListener {
        val sharedPrefs = context
            .getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        sharedPrefs.edit().putString("postId", EDITTEXTID).apply()

        (context as FragmentActivity)
            .supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, FRAGMENTA/B/C )
            .addToBackStack(null).commit()


    }
```

Replace uppercase with relevant Ids.

And get the value on the other Fragment like this

```
val preference = context?.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    if (preference != null) {
        getTextValue = preference.getString("postId", "none").toString()
                }
```

Remember that your `putString` key and `getString` has to be the **same**.